# Change the size of some words in ``tabular`` and align them

Tags: tabularx, fontsize, size

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{pifont} %bouni
\usepackage[french]{babel}

\usepackage[tikz]{bclogo}   % it load graphicx too
\usepackage{fancybox}       % pour faire l'encadrement

\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{left=1.5cm,right=1.5cm,top=1.5cm,bottom=1.5cm}

%---------------------------------------------------------------%
\begin{document}
%------------%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%begin entete pour mes TD%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%------
\noindent
\begin{tabular}[t]{@{}c@{}}
\makebox[\textwidth][s]{%
  \small
  \begin{tabular}{@{}l@{}}
 \quad \quad  \quad  République ......\\
Ministère de l'Enseignement Supérieur\\
\quad  et de la Recherche Scientifique \\
 \quad \quad  \quad   Université de ...... \\
Faculté des Sciences \'Economiques\\
\quad \quad et de Gestion de ......
  \end{tabular}
  \hfill
\begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}}
\includegraphics[height=3\normalbaselineskip]{example-image-9x16}
\end{tabular}
\hfill
  \begin{tabular}{@{}r@{}}
 République .......\\
Ministère de l'Enseignement Supérieur\\
\quad  et de la Recherche Scientifique \\
\vphantom{\large \'E} Université de ...... \\
Faculté des Sciences \'Economiques\\
\quad \quad et de Gestion de ......
\end{tabular}%
}% end of top row
%\\[4ex]
%\shadowbox{\Large\ding{45} \bfseries Travaux Dirigés d'Analyse N°{\huge4}}
\end{tabular}
%--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%\vspace{-1em}
\vspace{0.0cm}
        \begin{center}
            \shadowbox{
                \fbox{ \parbox{.85\linewidth}{ \centering\textbf{\textsf{\large{{\huge{E}}xamen Final en Mathématiques {\huge{I}}} (Session principale) } } \par
                \textbf{08 Junvier 2022} ( 11h.00 \ding{217} 12h.30 )
    }}
    }
\end{center}
%-------attention----- Une présentation générale soignée sera appréciée.
\vspace{-0.4cm}
\begin{center}
{\Large{\ding{43}}} \emph{\texttt{\textbf{\underline{N.B}}}}:
\emph{\texttt{\textbf{Aucun document n'est autorisé. Seules les calculatrices non-programmables et non graphiques sont autorisées. Il sera tenu compte de la rigueur et de la clarté de la rédaction. Cet énoncé comporte $4$ exercices indépendants.}}}
\end{center}
%-------------- FIN DE L'ENTETE----------------------
\end{document}
```

> I want that the design of the sentences in the right are like the one in the left. Also I appreciate any modifications which improve the form of my exam. Thanks a lot.

[image]

I hope that the design of writing will be like the following or better

[image]

Comment: Please make your document example minimal that your problem will be more clear. From document preamble remove all packages and your definitions, which are not related to your problem. Also remove all duplicate to leaded packages.

Comment: Remove `\quad` and use `@{}c@{}` in the `tabular` specification.

Comment: `\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc} % not needed in new latex versions` that comment is misleading. If your file is still in the legacy latin1 encoding then you do need that line. You do not need to declare UTF-8 in current releases if your file is in UTF-8.

Comment: @Student In the `tabular` specification! I meant `\begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}}`, sorry for not having been clear.

Comment: @Student Sorry, but that will never make into a nice exam sheet, unless you give up with big letters and shaded boxes.

Comment: What is wrong with my answer? What in it is not up-to date? And why you down-wote it?

Comment: Dear Professor Zarko. I cannot compile your answer and according to your pic it does not solve my question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I guess that you like to have something like this:

[image]

(red lines show page layout)

for which I use the following MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{pifont} %bouni
\usepackage[french]{babel}

\usepackage[tikz]{bclogo}   % it load graphicx too
\usepackage{fancybox}       % pour faire l'encadrement

\usepackage{tabularray}

%---------------- Show page layout. Don't use in a real document!
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.15pt}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}
%---------------------------------------------------------------%

\begin{document}

\noindent\begin{tblr}{colspec={@{} X[1.2,c] X[c] r X[0.8,l] @{}}}
\SetCell[r=5]{} 
Ministère de l'Enseignement Supérieur
et de la Recherche Scientifique

Université de \dotfill\par 
Faculté des Sciences 'Economiques 
et de Gestion de \dotfill
    &   \SetCell[r=5]{c} \includegraphics[height=3\baselineskip]{example-image-9x16}
        &   Année Universitaire:    &    2021-2022                          \\
    &   &                           &                                       \\
    &   &   \ding{42} Filière:      &   Licence en Sciences de Gestion      \\
    &   &   Niveau:                 &   Première année                      \\
    &   &  \textbf{Chargé du cours :} & Mr. \dotfill
\end{tblr}%

\begin{center}
\shadowbox{\parbox{.9\linewidth}{\centering\bfseries
    {\large\huge E}xamen Final en Mathématiques {\large\huge I}\quad
     (Session principale)\par
     08 Junvier 2022 
     \normalfont    ( 11h.00 \ding{217} 12h.30 )
        }}
        
\bigskip
\raisebox{-3pt}{\Large{\ding{43}}}
\itshape\bfseries\ttfamily

        
\bigskip
\raisebox{-3pt}{\Large{\ding{43}}}
\itshape\bfseries\ttfamily
\underline{N.B}: Aucun document n'est autorisé. Seules les calculatrices non-programmables et non graphiques sont autorisées. Il sera tenu compte de la rigueur et de la clarté de la rédaction. Cet énoncé comporte $4$ exercices indépendants.
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

As you can see, I a wee bit change your page design (that to my opinion looks a bit more nice).

**Addendum:**
Since you limit focus of question to the second image, below is an attempt to reproduce it. In this I'm somehow limited, since I haven't image of used image for logo used in your image (consequently package `bclogo` is not used) I use example image defined in `graphicx` package,  and since you not provide Arabic text, I simulate it with some (dummy) English one.

It is not clear (at least to me) if this image is on the top of each page of your document (consequently is part of document heading) or joust on the first page. In MWE below is considered later case.

Due to your changes the solution is now simpler as before. Table has only three equal width columns which contents are horizontal centered. For vertical position of cells contents are exploited options offered by `tabularray` package: `h`: at cell head, `t`: at cell top. For correct positioning of image its baseline is shifted to the top of image by image option `valign=m`, which is defined in the `adjustbox` package.

MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[margin=25mm]{geometry}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{pifont} %bouni
\usepackage[french]{babel}

%\usepackage[tikz]{bclogo}      % it load graphicx too
%\usepackage{fancybox}          % pour faire l'encadrement

\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}  % it load graphicx too
                                % needed for vertical positioning of image
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{varwidth}       % needed for inserting image

%---------------- Show page layout. Don't use in a real document!
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.15pt}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}
%---------------------------------------------------------------%

\begin{document}

\noindent\begin{tblr}{colspec={@{} X[c,h] X[c,t] X[c,h] @{}},
                      rows ={font=\footnotesize},   % <---
                      measure=\vbox                 % <---
                      }
{\textbf{\normalsize    République Tunisienne}\\[1ex]
Ministére de l'Enseignement Supérieur
et de la Rechereche Sientifique\\[1ex]
\scriptsize
Concourse Nationaux d'Entrée aux Cycles
de Formation d'Ingénieurs\\
Sesion 2017}
    &   \includegraphics[height=5\baselineskip,valign=t]% size should be adjusted 
                                                        % to size of real image
        {example-image-duck-portrait}   % I haven't your image, so is used example image
        &   {probably translation to Arabic\\
             \large 
             \textbf{\normalsize    not typed in OP MWE
                                    not typed in OP MWE}\\[1ex]
             \scriptsize
             formatted on the samo way as is the first column\\
                2017}
\end{tblr}%
\end{document}
```

[image]

(red lines indicate page layout)

Use code from above MWE in the first one should not be a big problem. In the first MWE only replace table code with above proposed, and extend preamble with packages and libraries, which are added to the second NWE.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But it does not compites to me. According to the pic it consumes a lot of spaces

Comment: Your question is not clear ... you like to have more spaces around image? I will add this

Comment: No Professor I just would like to improve the form of the sentences in the left

Comment: Well, than consider comment below  your question. Anyway, I will left my answer, maybe someone will find it useful ...

Comment: When I compiltes a message says ''tabularray.sty''not found

Comment: @Student, this means that you not have installed it. You need to install it. Package is on CTAN.

Comment: I think I have the complete version. How to install it?

Comment: Which LaTeX distribution you use? If you have MiKTeX, than open MiKTeX Console,  klick on button packages and there find `tabularray` package and then click on + button.

Comment: I use winedt 5.6 but for Miktek I installed the complete version

Comment: @Student, anyway try to  install it. Package is relative new. and may not be considered in your full installation.

Comment: I download the package from this link but I don't know where I should copy it? Thanks Professor https://ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/tabularray

Comment: You should do this by use of MiKTeX Console. Than it will be created maps for all its packages and stored on the right place. Download this again as I described in one of previous my comment.

Answer (score 1):

This  a simpler approach for designing a compact header for the first page of the exam. No additional packages are needed.

It uses three minipages side by side.

The text on the left has four different hierarchy lines that require different font sizes and line spacing.

To this end we use `\fontsize{<font size>}{<baselineskip>}\selectfont`. A `\par` is needed at the end of the paragraph to get the correct line spacing, before resetting the font.

In the example, the text on the right is a copy of the one on the left.

[image: a]

```
%------------%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%begin entete pour mes TD%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%------
\noindent\begin{minipage}{0.4\textwidth}
    \centering\bfseries 
    {\fontsize{10}{12}\selectfont   République Tunisienne \par}\vspace*{4pt}%
    {\fontsize{8}{8}\selectfont     Ministère de l'Enseignement Supérieur  \\ et de la Recherche Scientifique \par }\vspace*{3pt}%%
    {\fontsize{8}{8}\selectfont     Université de ......\par}\vspace*{3pt}%
    {\fontsize{6}{6}\selectfont     Faculté des Sciences \'Economiques \\ et de Gestion de Tunis\par}%
\end{minipage}
    \hfill
\begin{minipage}{0.1\textwidth}
\centering\includegraphics[height=3\normalbaselineskip]{example-image-9x16}
\end{minipage}
    \hfill
\begin{minipage}{0.4\textwidth}
    \centering\bfseries 
    {\fontsize{10}{12}\selectfont   République Tunisienne \par}\vspace*{4pt}%
    {\fontsize{8}{8}\selectfont     Ministère de l'Enseignement Supérieur \\ et de la Recherche Scientifique \par }\vspace*{3pt}%%
    {\fontsize{8}{8}\selectfont     Université de ......\par}\vspace*{3pt}%
    {\fontsize{6}{6}\selectfont     Faculté des Sciences \'Economiques \\ et de Gestion de Tunis\par}%
\end{minipage}
%------------%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%end entete pour mes TD%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%------
```

The second example considers that the right text is in Arabic.

In this case we need to add that language and use `fonspec`. The code must be compiled using `xelatex` or `lualatex`.

Notice that the layout of the right Arabic text is now slightly different than the left side in French, following the figure of the desired layout.

[image: z]

```
% !TeX TS-program =xelatex  

\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}

% **************************  added for arabic text
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage[main=french,bidi=default]{babel}
\babelprovide[import]{arabic}
\babelfont[arabic]{rm}{Times New Roman}
% **************************

\usepackage{showframe}% only to show margins <<<<<<<<<<<<<<
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{blue}}

\usepackage{pifont} %bouni

\usepackage[tikz]{bclogo}   % it load graphicx too
\usepackage{fancybox}       % pour faire l'encadrement

\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{left=1.5cm,right=1.5cm,top=1.5cm,bottom=1.5cm}

%---------------------------------------------------------------%
\begin{document}
%------------%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%begin entete pour mes TD%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%------
\noindent\begin{minipage}{0.4\textwidth}
    \centering\bfseries 
    {\fontsize{10}{12}\selectfont  République Tunisienne \par}\vspace*{4pt}%
    {\fontsize{8}{8}\selectfont    Ministère de l'Enseignement Supérieur  \\ et de la Recherche Scientifique \par }\vspace*{3pt}%%
    {\fontsize{8}{8}\selectfont    Université de ......\par}\vspace*{3pt}%
    {\fontsize{6}{6}\selectfont    Faculté des Sciences \'Economiques \\ et de Gestion de Tunis\par}%
\end{minipage}
    \hfill
\begin{minipage}{0.1\textwidth}
\centering\includegraphics[height=3\normalbaselineskip]{Coat_of_arms_of_Tunisia.png}
\end{minipage}
    \hfill
    \begin{minipage}{0.4\textwidth}
    \centering\bfseries 
    \begin{otherlanguage}{arabic}
    {\fontsize{9}{12} الجمهورية التونسية  \par}\vspace*{3pt}%
    {\fontsize{14}{17}\selectfont وزارة التعليم العالي والبحث العلمي  \par }\vspace*{3pt}%  وزارة التعليم العالي والبحث العلمي
    {\fontsize{10}{12}\selectfont   جامعة ال    ......\par}\vspace*{3pt}%
    {\fontsize{8}{8}\selectfont     كلية الاقتصاد والتسيير بتونس \par}%
\end{otherlanguage}
\end{minipage}  
%------------%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%end entete pour mes TD%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%------ 

    %\vspace{-1em}
    \vspace{0.0cm}
    \begin{center}
        \shadowbox{
            \fbox{ \parbox{.85\linewidth}{ \centering\textbf{\textsf{\large{{\huge{E}}xamen Final en Mathématiques {\huge{I}}} (Session principale) } } \par
                    \textbf{08 Janvier 2022} ( 11h.00 \ding{217} 12h.30 )
            }}
        }
    \end{center}
    %-------attention----- Une présentation générale soignée sera appréciée.
    \vspace{-0.4cm}
    \begin{center}
        {\Large{\ding{43}}} \emph{\texttt{\textbf{\underline{N.B}}}}:
        \emph{\texttt{\textbf{Aucun document n'est autorisé. Seules les calculatrices non-programmables et non graphiques sont autorisées. Il sera tenu compte de la rigueur et de la clarté de la rédaction. Cet énoncé comporte $4$ exercices indépendants.}}}
    \end{center}
    %-------------- FIN DE L'ENTETE----------------------
\end{document}
```

The figure is from [Coat_of_arms_of_Tunisia](https://commons.wikimedia.org/w/index.php?title=File:Coat_of_arms_of_Tunisia.svg&lang=fr&uselang=fr)